# How do I use "goto" in C++

Tags: c++, class, goto

When ı use goto in class in c++ ,I faced to that message,how can ı use goto in class c++?

```
In member function `void note_system::student_no()':
  label 'stop' used but not defined`
```

Comment: please add your code.

Comment: Why are you using `goto` - Was that consigned to the history books in the '80s? (along with dodgy fashion and haircuts)

Comment: I can tell you with 99.9% certainty that whatever you're doing with `goto` can be done better without.

Comment: Which part of the error message don't you understand?

Comment: [***"How bad can it be?"***](http://xkcd.com/292/)

Comment: You need to fix your time machine. No use being stuck in the 1960s. But -1 for asking a question about your code and them omitting that code.

Comment: **downvoters - "never say never"**

Answer (score 1):

You would do something like this (to have a single scope exit point, say when for some exotic reason using a RAII-based trick is not possible):

```
status_code func_with_goto() {
    if (i_see_errors()) goto func_end;
    ...
    func_end:
        return status_code::error;
}
```

Or like this (to emulate break-by-label-like behavior):

```
outer: while (...) {
    inner: while (...) {
        ...
        goto outer;
    }
}
```

Or if you just want to reimplement your second `Basic` program from 80-th in `C++`:

```
x10: std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
x20: goto x10;
```

There are very few cases where `goto` may be justified. Its presence complicates static code analysis by both humans and compilers. This does not mean at all that `goto` should be banned, it should just be use with double care.

Comment: I haven't seen a proper use for this in C++. In C, it's reasonable, but C++ has RAII.

Comment: @chris goto is still useful, although most times, a proper loop does the same logic, but cleaner. RAII has nothing to do with gotos, in my opinion.

Comment: @stefan It surely does. It solves the problem that sometimes leads C programmers to use goto.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Well yes, if you use gotos to perform clean-up, then one should switch to RAII, but apart from that it's completely orthogonal.

Comment: I put double loops in another function and return out of them

Comment: @stefan When else is goto a good idea?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I personally have used them recently in a `switch`: http://pastie.org/8901481

Comment: @stefan I'd reject that code immediately at a review

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Well then, care to propose a better alternative?

Comment: @chris - the question was "how", not "when" :)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I've had code where I've got a list of objects with fields a, b, c, d (already sorted by a and b), and where I had to process all records, with two levels of grouping, and set up some additional bits when I started working on a new group. The readable and intuitive flowchart didn't really translate to any construct better than `goto` with `NewA` and `NewB` labels. (And looking at stefan's code, I thought I had a simple suggestion, but that doesn't actually work in this case, so I'm interested too in knowing how you'd rewrite it.)

Comment: @hvd That's certainly a possibility, I don't know yet if I prefer it, but I can get the general idea to work. Thanks for proposing it!

Comment: @stefan Heh, I actually deleted my comment when I noticed that it would change the behaviour of your code, but if it's close enough for your needs, then I'm glad it was useful anyway. :)

Comment: @hvd in this case it is trivial to write `return Functor<int>::call(argc, argv);`

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Indeed. That causes the sort of unnecessary and unwanted code duplication, though, that I've always tried to avoid. For me personally, in that case, `goto` is easier to follow than your suggestion.

Comment: @hvd The duplication is marginal at most. It's a one liner return. Of exactly the same nature as many others in that code. And you can at least see that there is a direct return. For a more complex clause with multiple lines of code you would extract to a method.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I think we may have had this discussion before, and while I'm sure we can agree that code should be kept as readable as possible, and that `goto` generally decreases readability, we disagree on how much, and as a result will not be able to agree on when the benefits outweigh the costs.

Comment: @hvd These are always subjective to a degree. As gotos go, this is pretty borderline. Perhaps I'm too dogmatic. Then again, I think it can be dogmatic to remove all conceivable duplication. I don't find that return statement to violate DRY. You probably disagree. Which is just cool.